# What does the phrase "rushing off down" mean?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, sentence-meaning

What movement does John make according to the sentence? This sentence is taken from a dictionary, which explains the usage of "go".

> John went rushing off down the corridor.

Comment: Do you have the name of the dictionary and a link to it? The more details you put  in your question, the better it is.

Comment: The specific movement would likely be a fast walk, not a run. (But it's open to interpretation.)

Comment: longman dictionary, http://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/go_1, thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Possibly the best way to explain is with some practical examples:

> Before I could warn him that the floor was wet, **John went rushing off down the corridor** and slipped over.
>
> As soon as he heard that there were fresh doughnuts in the canteen, **John went rushing off down the corridor** to get some.

The phrase 'Hurried away' is generally interchangeable.

EDIT

In this context, **down** is the direction that John went. It's commonly used in English but ambiguous - you could, just as easily, have used 'up' or 'along'.

To '**rush off**' is a phrasal verb meaning to hurry away.

Just to confuse things even further for the unfortunate learner, there is an alternative meaning for the phrasal verb 'rush off' meaning to be busy - I'm rushed off my feet today

Comment: Thank you. why are there two adverb off, down, are they exactly used to describe movement, I am totally confused by them.

Comment: @cody down is the direction. It's commonly used in English but ambiguous - you could, just as easily, have used 'up' or 'along'. To 'rush off' is a phrasal verb meaning to hurry away. Just to confuse things even further for the unfortunate learner, there is an alternative meaning for the phrasal verb 'rush off' meaning to be busy - I'm rushed off my feet today.

Comment: @PerryW These would be good points to add to your answer.

Comment: @user3169 Good suggestion - done

Comment: @PerryW - Interesting observation about the phrasal "rush off" - I've never heard that one in US English.

Comment: @stangdon It is a normal usage to me. For example, you might hear "Don't rush off!" in response to someone trying to avoid having to do something.

Comment: @user3169 - Sorry, I was a bit unclear on what I meant.  Yes, I'm familiar with "to rush off" as meaning "to hurry away".  But "I'm rushed off my feet" is unfamiliar to me.

Comment: @stangdon Agreed. I have not heard that one in the US either.

Comment: Interesting, the usage for 'busy' is so common in BrEng and AusEng that I assumed it was global. The OED references go back to 1887 and an Ngram check https://goo.gl/U22RVe shows it magically appearing and taking off in popularity from 1903. But you're right, while I can find quotes from US sources, they seem to be pastes or re-quotes from BrEng originals.